# I want to show only those ClaimID where all the status is either success or fail

Tags: sql-server

| ClaimID | CategoryID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | success |
| 1 | b | null |
| 1 | c | fail |
| 2 | a | success |
| 2 | b | success |
| 2 | c | fail |
| 3 | a | null |
| 3 | b | null |
| 3 | c | null |

I want to show only those `ClaimID` where all the `Status` is either `'success'` or `'fail'`.
The result should be 2.

Comment: Your categoryID does not have success nor fail. Do you mean the Statis?

Comment: Yes. The result should be only 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY ClaimID` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ClaimID
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY ClaimID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(Status)  -- there are not any nulls
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0059baa8400d1f0576c6436da4aac7c6).
Result:

```
> | ClaimID |
> | ------: |
> |       2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the following

```
SELECT T.ClaimID
FROM YourTable AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM YourTable AS T2 WHERE T.CliamID=T2.ClaimID AND T2.Status IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the below query should work

```
create table #YourTable  (ClaimID INT, CategoryID VARCHAR(10) ,[Status]VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES
(1,'a', 'success'),(1,'b', null),(1,'c', 'fail'),(2,'a', 'success'),
(2,'b', 'success'),(2,'c', 'fail'),(3,'a', null),(3,'b', null),(3,'c', null)

SELECT
ClaimID,
CategoryID,
[Status]
FROM #YourTable
WHERE [Status] IN ('success','fail')
DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

Output

```
ClaimID CategoryID  Status
1         a         success
1         c         fail
2         a         success
2         b         success
2         c         fail
```

Comment: No, I only want that claimID who's all categoryID status is either success or fail but not null.